# WPDB - How to search a column in a table

Tags: wpdb

I have a custom table called wpgrating

I have a column there called "ip"

Now what I want to do is search for "ip" column and see if there is an entry already there?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In a WP template, plugin, PHPMyAdmin or from where are you trying to achieve this?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the whole column? Or just the value in that column (including whether or not it exists) for a specific given row?

Comment: For now I am using it in template for now but its actually will be used in plugin. .I will check solutions and will update here..

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for should be straight SQL.

Try adapting the following:

```
function check_for_ip($ip) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT true
        FROM `wpgrating`
        WHERE `ip` = %s
SQL;
    return (bool) $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $ip));
}
```

In essence, we do a simple `SELECT` with the IP in question as in the `WHERE` clause. (Note that it's important that we don't use the otherwise standard `SELECT 1` as WordPress' database abstractor will always return `false` for that.) Because we are not selecting an entire row, we avoid a lot of overhead..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
global $wpdb;
$ip = "120.0.0.1"

$ip_row = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wpgrating WHERE ip LIKE %s", $ip));

if($ip_row)
    return "IP exists";
else
    return "IP does not exist";
```

Its pretty straight forward but still this is whats going on. What I understand from the question is that the user wants to find out, if an ip address already exists in the database. Using the $wpdb class we search for the specific IP address. If it exists it would return an object containing the full row for that IP. If not, $ip_row would be empty.

Comment: An answer should not be raw code dump. Please add more explanation and see [answer]

Comment: That is not correct/safe use of `prepare()` method.

Comment: @Rarst Yes it would probably throw a warning with the current version of WordPress. I have fixed it.